# FTP and Convert text file from UNICODE to UTF-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ftp, navicat

Does anyone know of a way schedule or automate copying or ftping a UNICODE text file and have it converted to a UTF-8 encoding?

The file I am attempting is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\MSFax\ActivityLog\OutboxLOG.txt.  I can re-save it as a UTF-8 in notepad and that allows me to import it into navicat mysql.  But, I have to copy it to another directory before it will allow me to import it since MS FAX has it in use.

Comment: First of all, Unicode isn't an encoding. A file can't be "Unicode encoded", it must be UTF-8, UTF-16 or any other of the Unicode encodings encoded. Secondly, what problem do you have transmitting it over FTP?

Comment: If I open this file in notepad and go to "Save As".  The default file type is Unicode, the other option is UTF-8.  So, it is saved as unicode.

Comment: Yeah, that's just Notepad's terminology being terrible. What Notepad calls "Unicode" is actually UTF-16. The best proof I could find for that is [here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities_editors.html#notepad). Just trust me that *there is no "Unicode" encoding.* Unicode is *the standard*, but it's not an [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP supports only [four transfer types](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#TYPE): ASCII, EBCDIC, binary, and "local" (for 9-bit bytes, yes there are systems that have 9-bit bytes). UNICODE and UTF-8 are not supported. You will have to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: @Raymond Are you saying one can't transfer UTF-8/Unicode encoded files over FTP?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that FTP does not support UTF-8/Unicode autoconversion (which is what the OP was asking for). You can still transfer them as binary.

Comment: Ok, that required some clarification. I'm not really expecting FTP to do *any* sort of charset conversion though, so this is not limited to Unicode encodings.